# Plotting a distance matrix according to another distance matrix

Tags: r, plot, multivariate-testing, distance-matrix

So I have 50 samples, for which I have data on the chemical composition, and the spatial coordinates.

With those, I created a Bray-Curtis dissimilarity matrix of the chemical similarity between samples, and a distance matrix based on the spatial coordinates (Euclidean distances).

I would like to plot the similarity of each pair of sample according to the spatial distance between them.

Is there a way to do that in R ?

I did create Mantel correlograms based on those data, but I would also like a basic visualisation of the evolution of pairwise similarity with the spatial distance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Laurence Jeanjean! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.